# Passing Argument to a Generator to build a tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tf.keras, tf.data.dataset

I am trying to build a tensorflow dataset from a generator. I have a list of tuples called some_list , where each tuple has an integer and some text.

**When I do not pass some_list as an argument to the generator, the code works fine**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np

some_list=[(1,'One'),[2,'Two'],[3,'Three'],[4,'Four'],
      (5,'Five'),[6,'Six'],[7,'Seven'],[8,'Eight']]

def text_gen1():
    random.shuffle(some_list)
    size=len(some_list)
    i=0
    while True:
    
        yield some_list[i][0],some_list[i][1]
        i+=1
        if i>size:
            i=0
            random.shuffle(some_list)
#Not passing any argument
tf_dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(text_gen1,output_types=(tf.int32,tf.string),
                                        output_shapes = ((),()))
for count_batch in tf_dataset1.repeat().batch(3).take(2):
    print(count_batch)
```

> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([7, 1, 2])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'Seven', b'One', b'Two'], dtype=object)>)
> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([3, 5, 4])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'Three', b'Five', b'Four'], dtype=object)>)

**However, when I try to pass some_list as an argument, the code fails**

```
def text_gen2(file_list):
random.shuffle(file_list)
size=len(file_list)
i=0
while True:
    
    yield file_list[i][0],file_list[i][1]
    i+=1
    if i>size:
        i=0
        random.shuffle(file_list)

tf_dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(text_gen2,args=[some_list],output_types= 
(tf.int32,tf.string),output_shapes = ((),()))
for count_batch in tf_dataset1.repeat().batch(3).take(2):
    print(count_batch)
```

> ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.

I noticed , when I try to pass a list of integers as an argument , the code works. However, a list of tuples seems to make it crash. Can someone shed some light on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is what it says is, you cannot have heterogeneous data types (`int` and `str`) in the same `tf.Tensor`. I did a few changes and came up with the code below.

- Separate your `some_list` to two lists using `zip()`, i.e. `int_list` and `str_list` and make your generator function accept two lists.
- I don't understand why you're manually shuffling stuff within the generator. You can do it in a cleaner way using `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np

some_list=[(1,'One'),[2,'Two'],[3,'Three'],[4,'Four'],
      (5,'Five'),[6,'Six'],[7,'Seven'],[8,'Eight']]

def text_gen2(int_list, str_list):
  
  for x, y in zip(int_list, str_list):      
      yield x, y
  

tf_dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    text_gen2,
    args=list(zip(*some_list)),
    output_types=(tf.int32,tf.string),output_shapes = ((),())
)

i = 0
for count_batch in tf_dataset2.repeat().batch(4).shuffle(buffer_size=6):
    print(count_batch)
    i += 1
    if i > 10: break;
```